# How to array merge in case same name in array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

i have array with multiple array values i want to form new array in existing array values ,if plotting type same it return single array and calulate Time of same plotting time.

```
Actual Array:
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 00:45
                [PlottingType] => Research
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 00:45
                [PlottingType] => admin
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 00:45
                [PlottingType] => admin
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 00:45
                [PlottingType] => Research
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 00:30
                [PlottingType] => Research
            )

    )

    Expected Array:

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 01:30
                [PlottingType] => Research
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Time] => 01:30
                [PlottingType] => admin
            )


    )
```

Calulate same plotting type time into single index into single array.so please suggest appropriate solution.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're using PHP? (based on your sample)

Comment: `[Time] => 01:30 [PlottingType] => Research` - may be `02:00`?

Comment: @Sami it has expected output, scroll listing down

Comment: @abhiv why 02.15?? 0:45 + 0:45 + 0:30 = 2:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
  array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'Research'),
  array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'admin'),
  array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'admin'),
  array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'Research'),
  array('Time' => '00:30', 'PlottingType' => 'Research'),
);

print_r(array_reduce($data, function($result, $item) {
    $key = $item['PlottingType'];
    if (!isset($result[$key]))
       $result[$key] = $item;
    else
    {
       list($h1, $m1) = explode(':', $result[$key]['Time']);
       list($h2, $m2) = explode(':', $item['Time']);
       $time = ($h1 + $h2) * 60 + $m1 + $m2;
       $h = floor($time / 60);
       $m = $time % 60;
       $result[$key]['Time'] = str_pad($h, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . 
                               str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $result;
}, array()));
```

It is possible to play with `strtotime` and `date`, but I did not want to, so the code is slightly longer. If you want to remove final keys from the result - apply function `array_values` to it.

Result

```
Array
(
    [Research] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 02:00
            [PlottingType] => Research
        )

    [admin] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 01:30
            [PlottingType] => admin
        )

)
```

ps: and another way

```
print_r(array_reduce($data, function($result, $item) {
    $key = $item['PlottingType'];
    if (!isset($result[$key]))
       $result[$key] = $item;
    else
    {
       $time = strtotime('0:' . $result[$key]['Time']);
       list($h, $m) = explode(':', $item['Time']);
       $time = strtotime('+' . $h . ' minutes', $time);
       $time = strtotime('+' . $m . ' seconds', $time);
       $result[$key]['Time'] = date('i:s', $time);
    }
    return $result;
}, array()));
```

Here I used minutes as seconds and hours as minutes, so the answer could have more than 24 hours, up to 60.

pps: ok, you can not assign it to the variable by yourself, I'll write it down for you

```
$data = array_values(array_reduce($data, function($result, $item) {
      $key = $item['PlottingType'];
      if (!isset($result[$key]))
         $result[$key] = $item;
      else
      {
         $time = strtotime('0:' . $result[$key]['Time']);
         list($h, $m) = explode(':', $item['Time']);
         $time = strtotime('+' . $h . ' minutes', $time);
         $time = strtotime('+' . $m . ' seconds', $time);
         $result[$key]['Time'] = date('i:s', $time);
      }
      return $result;
}, array()));
```

Comment: answer is correct, but which is the final array ,for return . because you print the whole array.

Comment: remove function `print_r()` and assign result to another variable.

Comment: i want only single key not diffrent key.. like '$result['eventlist'][]".

Comment: I made exactly the same array as you asked. And I wrote - if you do not want the key, apply `array_values()` to the result.

Comment: @abhiv I've added assignment to the variable for you. I checked all the codes - no errors there, it means that you made something wrong.

Comment: sory its my mistak.. perfect result return. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to remove the duplicates in an array. In that case use `array_unique()` function.

```
$expectedarray = array_unique($actualarray);
print_r($expectedarray);
```

If you want to count the values use `array_count_values()` intead `array_unique()`

For more information, refer here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: is it correct, but also i want to calculate time of same plotting type.

Comment: You want sum of time_plot?

Answer (score 0):

```
$expectedarray = array();
foreach($ar as $yourmainarray)
{
    foreach($u as $expectedarray)
    {
        if($ar['PlottingType'] == $u['PlottingType'])
        {
             $u['Time'] = $u['Time'] + $ar['Time'];
        }
        else
        {
             array_push($ar, $expectedarray);
        }
    }
}
```

it will give output like this

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 2:00
            [PlottingType] => Research
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 01:30
            [PlottingType] => admin
        )
```

You can check it as

```
foreach($u as $expectedarray)
{
    print_r($u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am deleting old answer and this is the new working one. I hoped that you can do small changes required.

```
function add_minutes($time_1, $time_2) {
    $temp = explode(':', $time_1);
    $hr_1 = $temp[0]; $min_1 = $temp[1];
    $temp = explode(':', $time_2);
    $hr_2 = $temp[0]; $min_2 = $temp[1];

    $min_2 = $min_2+$min_1;
    $min_1 = intval($min_2/60);
    $hr_2 = $hr_2 + $hr_1;
    $hr_2 += $min_1;
    $min_2 = $min_2%60;
    $min_2 = sprintf('%02d', $min_2); $hr_2 = sprintf('%02d', $hr_2);
    return $hr_2.':'.$min_2;
}

$actual_array = array();
$actual_array[] = array('Time' => '01:45', 'PlottingType' => 'Research');
$actual_array[] = array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'admin');
$actual_array[] = array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'admin');
$actual_array[] = array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'Research');
$actual_array[] = array('Time' => '00:45', 'PlottingType' => 'Research');

$single_array = array();

foreach($actual_array as $val) {
    if (key_exists($val['PlottingType'], $single_array)) {
        $single_array[$val['PlottingType']] = add_minutes($val['Time'], $single_array[$val['PlottingType']]);
    } else {
        $single_array[$val['PlottingType']] = $val['Time'];
    }
}

$output_array = array();
foreach ($single_array as $key => $value) {
    $output_array[] = array('PlottingType' => $key, 'Time' => $value);
}

// $output_array this is your answer.
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: pls convert time to minute.